# ActiveSupport::TestCase won't run DB commands?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I have 3 questions:

1. What is the default testing library that comes with Rails? I can't actually see what it's called... MiniTest? TestUnit?
2. How can I make some code run once **per TestCase** to setup for ALL tests. It seems `setup do` is run before each test, but I want to set up for the entire file.
3. How come my example below doesn't work (it won't clear out and re-create the seed data before each test)

Code:

```
require 'test_helper'

# negative numbers
# 3+ line item journal entries

class LedgerTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.each(&:delete_all)

    AccountType.create!(code: 101, name: 'Cash',                     category: :asset,     normal_balance: :debit)
    AccountType.create!(code: 102, name: 'Equipment',                category: :asset,     normal_balance: :debit)
    AccountType.create!(code: 103, name: 'Accumulated Depreciation', category: :asset,     normal_balance: :credit, contra: true)
  end

  test "test 1 here" do
  end

  test "test 2 here" do
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should separate this into 3 posts as it's easier.

## 1 ActiveSupport::TestCase framework

`ActiveSupport::TestCase` extends `Minitest::Test`

## 2 Setup before all examples in a file

As far as I know, all the ways to do it are workarounds. This is discouraged and not supported through a nice API by default. 
   Quick search comes up with this:

```
setup_executed = false
setup do
  unless setup_executed
    #code goes here
    setup_executed = true
  end
end
```

## 3 Setup not working

In development and test environments by default classes are autoloaded lazily, as they are required. Unless you reference a class somewhere in your code before running `ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses`, ruby won't know it exists, because it was never loaded.

Comment: hmm I see.. really I'm trying to clear the database out before all tests (so once at the beginning of the file), and then clear 1 particular table out before each test (so before each test). Should I just try to use rspec or something to do this? What is the recommended approach there?

Comment: @Tallboy This is probably what you're looking for then https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner

Comment: Does `ActiveSupport::TestCase` automatically clean out the database between each test? It's driving me crazy, but it seems it's already doing that? (without needing any extra gems)

Comment: You seem to be missing "test fixtures". A search for "Rails test fixtures" will reveal the wheel you are trying to reinvent here.